# cognito + API Gateway. getting status 401

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I wrapped the API made using Express with API Gateway.
And I am using Cognito Userpool to authenticate API Gateway.

When I accessed that API using Angular2 http service, normal value returned.
However, when authentication fails, it gets the following error.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I correctly set up the header mapping, but this time I get this error.

When I access it using Postman, I get the following result.

```
{

 "message": "Unauthorized"

}
```

I also want this same result when accessing with Angular2.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in some error cases (such as 401/403) API Gateway will not return CORS headers, even if properly configured.

We are aware this is a pain point for customers and are working on a solution, but cannot commit to a time frame for when it would be available.

Comment: I understand.The correspondence of aws makes me sad.

Comment: @tomoyaishizaka any update on this issue yet? How did you solve it?

Comment: @eldos, have a look at solution for it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913196/401-return-from-an-api-gateway-custom-authorizer-is-missing-access-control-allo/36922233