# zappa custom authorizer for flask with cors

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa, flask-cors

I am using flask-cors for a aws python aws lambda API. I deployed it with zappa, it worked as intended. Yet cors does not work with custom authorizer 
inspired by https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/master/blueprints/python/api-gateway-authorizer-python.py

I changed the authorizer code with try/except and generate a policy for OPTION method on exception, still Option method returns 401.

I do not mind a workaround if it makes things easy.

Thanks

I tried one of suggested solutions: that is to set headers for 401 responses in API Gateway, regretfully browser preflight expects a successful status code.

Update. I felt back on implementing my authorizer, also considered using aws auth service.

Comment: where is your code, how to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Please provide a simple git repo, so the issue can be debugged

Comment: Have you tried [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47122179/1252647)? I was having the same problem as you have.

Comment: Ok will try tonight, seems like a workaround, but good step by step instruction

Comment: Tried dashmug solution, regretfully still same 401 and no cors headers

Comment: I've updated my answer with some zappa configuration that might help.

Answer (score 1):

This [API Gateway problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913196/401-return-from-an-api-gateway-custom-authorizer-is-missing-access-control-allo) (which was confirmed by AWS people) has existed for months.

Luckily, they have recently (June 2017) published a way to fix it using [Gateway Responses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/customize-gateway-responses.html).

---

In your API Gateway console, go to your API and then **Gateway Responses**.

[image: Gateway Responses]

Look for *Unauthorized (401)* and add the following headers (you can use your domains, of course):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: '*'
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
```

See image below:

[image: Unauthorized]

Comment: tried, surprisingly did not work - got 401 without headers

Comment: could be some freaky permission?

Comment: Succeded with header after publishing the api change. POST still does not pass due Failed to load https://u.... : Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Comment: apparently browser expects "successful" status code

Answer (score 1):

- Getting a `401` from your `OPTIONS` method in API Gateway is very
  unusual.  I see `403`s and missing CORS headers on `OPTIONS` calls
  quite a bit, but generally not 401.  If there were a problem with your authorizer, I'd expect the 401 on the ensuing `POST`, not on the `OPTIONS` call.
- You also mentioned that you had been changing authorizer code in an
  effort to handle this.

Without seeing your API Gateway configuration, I can't say for sure, but these two bullet points suggest a possibility.  It *sounds like* your custom authorizer may be hooked up to your `OPTIONS` method (in addition to `POST` or whatever you're trying to expose).  This shouldn't be the case.

For example, if you attach a custom (token type) authorizer to the `OPTIONS` method of an API Gateway resource, and then make an `OPTIONS` call without an Authorization header, you'll get a `401`.

Your custom authorizer should only be attached to the methods you're explicitly exposing.  In many cases this is just `POST`, but could include others like `PUT`, `DELETE`, and so on.

If this isn't helpful, you might update the question with your API Gateway configuration, and the request/response headers from the failing `OPTIONS` call.

**UPDATE**

I deployed a HelloWorld flask app using Zappa, and I think I was able to reproduce your issue.  I'm using the blueprint you linked to for the custom authorizer.  Changing `policy.denyAllMethods()` to `policy.allowAllMethods()` was the only change I made to it.

When I deploy, something like this is created:

[image: APIG configuration without CORS]

I was able to get `401` from `OPTIONS` calls that did not contain an `Authorization` header.

I added `"cors": true` to my `zappa_settings`, which created something much more CORS friendly:

[image: APIG with CORS]

This configuration looks better.  No more `401` from `OPTIONS`, whether an `Authorization` header is present or not.

My `zappa_settings` with `"cors": true` added looks like this:

```
{
    "dev": {
        "app_function": "hello.app",
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "profile_name": null,
        "project_name": "flask",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-xxxxxxxxx",
        "cors": true
    },
    "authorizer": {
    "arn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:function:flask-authorizer",
    "result_ttl": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying work with zappa for one push button upload, which at the moment do not provide by method authorizers.

Comment: I tried to push 'enable cors' button that create OPTIONS resource without authorization yet did not help. Do you know how to unhook Options

Comment: @Serge I also had some trouble trying to "manually" enable CORS in the AWS console.  I updated my answer with something you could try.  Does your `zappa_settings` contain `"cors": true`?

Comment: produced though different error code 403 Forbidden Exception, no cors headers