# How to configure CORS for AWS API Gateway using OpenAPI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have an OpenAPI spec for an api which I am deploying via CDK.  The spec looks like:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: My API
  description: My REST API with CORS enabled
  version: 0.1.0

x-amazon-apigateway-cors:
  allowOrigins:
    - "*"
  allowCredentials: true
  exposeHeaders:
    - "x-apigateway-header"
    - "x-amz-date"
    - "content-type"
  maxAge: 3600
  allowMethods:
    - "*"
  allowHeaders":
    - "x-apigateway-header"
    - "x-amz-date"
    - "content-type"
    - "Authorization"

components:
  securitySchemes:
    lambda:
      type: "apiKey"
      name: "Authorization"
      in: "header"
      x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: "custom"
      x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
        authorizerUri: "{{my-lambda-authorizer}}"
        authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 300
        type: "token" 

paths:
  /user/{id}:
    get:
      summary: Get info of specified user.
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
      security:
        - lambda: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: "{{my-lambda}}"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "aws_proxy"
```

When I try to access this via `fetch()`, I get an error `Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

```
fetch('https://api.example.com/user/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((user: User) => {
            // do something
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
        });
```

The API is accessible at `api.example.com` and I am running the website locally using Gatsby at `localhost:8000`.

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-cors-configuration.html) seem to state that CORS is enabled when I put `x-amazon-apigateway-cors` at the root of the spec, but CORS doesn't seem to be enabled (or working) when I try to access the API.  How do I enable CORS for my API without needing to configure it in the console?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Amazon API Gateway offers two types of APIs: REST APIs and HTTP APIs. REST APIs were the kind of APIs originally introduced with Amazon API Gateway, while [HTTP APIs got announced at the end of 2019](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-http-apis-for-amazon-api-gateway/).

Based on the description of your OpenAPI specification I assume you're trying to deploy a REST API. The `x-amazon-apigateway-cors` OpenAPI extension however only works for HTTP APIs.

You have two choices now: You either switch to use a HTTP API or you configure CORS manually. As long as you don't need [features only supported by REST APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html), I suggest you switch to use a HTTP API, as that's the more modern kind of API Amazon API Gateway offers.

If you want to use a REST API, enabling CORS requires more manual configuration. That's documented by AWS in [Enabling CORS for a REST API resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html). Essentially you have to ensure your integration returns proper CORS headers. For a NodeJS AWS Lambda function that could look like:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

For CORS pre-flight requests to work you'd also have to ensure that OPTIONS-requests also return the correct headers. The easiest way to achieve that is to add a mock-integration for the OPTIONS-request to your OpenAPI specification. That would look like:

```yaml
options:
  responses:
    '200':
      description: Default response
      headers:
        Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
          schema:
            type: string
        Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
          schema:
            type: string
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
          schema:
            type: string
  x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
    type: mock
    requestTemplates:
      application/json: |
        {"statusCode" : 200}
    responses:
      default:
        statusCode: 200
        responseParameters:
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'OPTIONS,POST'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'https://example.com/'"
```

Please also mind that [modern browsers don't support localhost as origin for CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin), so you might need to work around that as well.

Comment: Thanks you, that's a remarkably helpful answer. You're right, it's a REST API as (a) it's the only one that supports OpenAPI via CDK and (b) I need to do authorization by inspecting a token as it doesn't look like a Cognito authorizer is rich enough for what I want. I've managed to get the CORS to work by returning the headers from within the proxy itself as per your answer, but only when I disable the custom lambda authorizer. Is there something more I need to do to be able to use a lambda authorizer here?

Comment: Does your client request successfully pass the authorizer? Because if not the authorizer will generate the responses, which won't contain the necessary CORS-headers.

Comment: Is there a way of having the authorizer return the headers? The docs suggest throwing an exception to indicate a 401, so I'm guessing that would cause the headers not to be passed.

Comment: Turns out there is another question on StackOverflow for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913196/401-return-from-an-api-gateway-custom-authorizer-is-missing-access-control-allo :-)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have followed these same steps from elsewhere, and am stuck at '403': 'It does not have HTTP ok status.' I have veried all response headers including HTTP 200/OK in curl, and am simply confused at this point!